# How to programmatically click a CheckBox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, checkbox

SO i have `CheckBox` and since there's no CheckBox.PerformClick() method in `WPF`, is there a way to click a WPF `CheckBox` programmatically?

I found this solution but this for `Button` only:

```
ButtonAutomationPeer peer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(someButton);
IInvokeProvider invokeProv = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
invokeProv.Invoke();
```

Comment: Isn't it easier just to CheckBox.Ischeck = !Checkbox.IsChecked ? Or do you want to achieve something else ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `PatternInterface.Toggle` interface to toggle the `CheckBox`:

```
CheckBoxAutomationPeer peer = new CheckBoxAutomationPeer(someCheckBox);
IToggleProvider toggleProvider = peer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Toggle) as IToggleProvider;
toggleProvider.Toggle();
```

Or you can set the `IsChecked` property:

```
someCheckBox.IsChecked = !someCheckBox.IsChecked;
```